# Error "\player.exe caused an Access Violation " when running Genymotion for Android emulator

Tags: genymotion

When I start running `GenyMotion` I got error `"player.exe has stopped working"`.

But when I check the file crash.txt on `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Genymobile` then the error said :

```
Error occured on Thursday, June 18, 2015 at 10:45:34.

C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\player.exe caused an Access Violation at location 06FA361C in module C:\Windows\system32\ig4icd32.dll Reading from location 00000000.

Registers:
eax=0bc73600 ebx=00000004 ecx=0bc95600 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=0bd79108
eip=06fa361c esp=0d18f3d0 ebp=0bd79100 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202

AddrPC   Params
06FA361C 00000001 00000004 00000000  ig4icd32.dll!ShSetEncryptionMethod
06FA7CDF 0BC95600 00000004 00000000  ig4icd32.dll!ShSetEncryptionMethod
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by doing the following:

I opened up virtual box and started the device from there with no problems. Then closed it and restarted it from Genymotion again and it worked. Tried this because the error prompt from Genymotion which says `"open the virtual device from VirtualBox to find out the cause"` . Not exactly sure how the access violation error relates to the above process though, but hopefully this helps.